# How to create relations of tree nodes efficiently in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have model Relation, that connects ancestor with **all** its descendants:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
    ancestor = models.ForeignKey('Node')
    descendant = models.ForeignKey('Node')
    # Number of edges between ancestor and descendant
    power = IntegerField()
```

And model Node:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    ...some data...
    def save(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_relations(parent)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I need to efficiently create relations between new node and ancestors. I managed to write the next function:

```
    def create_relations(self, parent):
        relations_of_parent = Relation.objects.filter(descendant=parent).values_list('ancestor', 'power')
        relations = []
        for ancestor, power in relations_of_parent:
            relations.append(Relation(ancestor=ancestor, descendant=self, power=power + 1))
        relations.append(Relation(ancestor=parent, descendant=self, power=1))
        Relation.objects.bulk_create(relations)
```

It would be good if there's only one hit database. Is there the way?

Comment: Without understanding your use case it's hard to know if your `Relation` approach is the best. Do you need to capture _all_ of those relations or would it be sufficient to have a tree of nodes that you can efficiently walk? I'd be looking at [`ForeignKey("self")`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships) to set this up. I haven't looked at the generated SQL, but I'd hope that this uses a recursive CTE on engines that support it.

Comment: @Chris, I need to store exactly all relations between ancestors and descendants